# VC++ dependency

Tags: visual-c++, dev-c++

I am working on a VC++ development(Tools). 
Our application is Dialog based application, which consisting of menus and operation with Access database with the help of SQL Queries.
One of the option from Menu is working in Windows 7 environment and the same is not responding in Windows 10(idle response after clicking that option from menu in Win10 OS).
we think that there is a dependency on dll.

---

**How to find the dependency for specific operation while executing tool?**

---

Expecting your support to find soln for this issue!!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Magesh.S

Answer (score 0):

Try with Process Monitor application from Microsoft site.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion "NetVicious" ... by the way isnt possible to find with visual studio through debugging?

Comment: Did you checked with the Process Monitor to check a `not found` file ?